# How do I return a 410 Error for no longer existing pages in firebase JSON?

Tags: seo

I’m trying to return a 410 error for a webpage no longer existing on my firebase hosted site.

How can I do this in Json file ?

Can this be done in Json or would I just have to do it through code in html instead?